# cannot resolve symbol sqlcontext in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea

my SPARK version is spark--version : 2.3.2.
while importing

```
import sqlContext.implicits
```

i am getting error :
**cannot resolve symbol sqlcontext**

i am using Intellij and scala 
Scala version 2.11.8

Kindly share your thoughts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The import you're trying will not work because the object is defined within the class [SQLContext](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/SQLContext.implicits$.html)

```
val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
import sqlContext.implicits._
```

Take a look at [Why import implicit SqlContext.implicits._ after initializing SQLContext in a scala spark application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42503558/why-import-implicit-sqlcontext-implicits-after-initializing-sqlcontext-in-a-sc)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You have to create the sqlContext object first from the SQLContext, see https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/SQLContext.implicits$.html. Otherwise, as it says, it doesn't know about such an objectl