# import sqlContext cannot be resolved although defined with SQLContext instance

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I followed the solutions in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53451011/cannot-resolve-symbol-sqlcontext-in-spark), however, I am still getting the "cannot resolve symbol SQLContext" error. ".implicits._" cannot be resolved either. What would be the reason for it?

Spark/Scala versions I use:

- Scala 2.12.13
- Spark 3.0.1 (without bundled Hadoop)

Here is my related code part:

```
    import org.apache.log4j.LogManager
    import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}    

    object Count {
    
      def main(args: Array[String]) {
          ...
          ...

          val sc = new SparkContext(conf)         

          val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
          import sqlContext.implicits._
      }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't import `SQLContext` at all:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
```

You should probably not use `SQLContext` anymore in the first place though:

> As of Spark 2.0, this is replaced by SparkSession. However, we are keeping the class here for backward compatibility.
>
> https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/SQLContext.html

See how to use a `SparkSession` from `SparkContext` at [How to create SparkSession from existing SparkContext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42935242/how-to-create-sparksession-from-existing-sparkcontext) and then `import sparkSession.implicits._`.